# Changing order in which custom fields appear in dashboard

Tags: custom-field

I have several custom fields for my CPT. In dashboard page of my CPT, when editing a CPT, I see my custom fields in "custom fields" box. But I want to change the order in which they are displayed. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about *the* WordPress custom fields (no external resource like plugin etc.), then the answer is: No, unfortunately not.

The [meta box](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php#L498) calls [`has_meta`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-admin/includes/post.php#L726) and [`list_meta`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-admin/includes/template.php#L456) - and none of these functions provides suitable filter/action hooks.

The custom fields are ordered by `meta_key,meta_id`.

---

Of course, you can set up your own meta box.

All you need to change is the call of `has_meta` - and adapt the SQL `ORDER BY` clause.